# Android Studio refresh RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add item from one adapter into another adapter. But  when I added item, doesn't appear in the another adapter's recyclerview list.

ContactDataAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactDataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.titleTv.setText(arrList.get(position).toString());
    holder.conIv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            CallFragment cf = new CallFragment();
            //CallDataAdapter cd = new CallDataAdapter();
            String t = holder.titleTv.getText().toString();
            cf.addItem(t.toString());
            //cd.addData(t);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Added " + t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

CallFragment.java

```
 public void addItem(String title) {
    adapter.addData(title.toString());
    //adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,data.size());
}
```

CallDataAdapter.java

```
public void addData(String title) {
    dataList.add(title);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, dataList.size());
    notifyItemInserted(pos + 1);
}
```

The Image that clicked added button

[image]

A list that diplay added item("asd" added from the beginning.)

[image]

Comment: Please clear your question

Comment: you are creating new object of `CallFragment` instance of that use https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus or interface for call the  `addItem` method in other fragment

Answer (score 0):

First setup [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

**Define events:**

```
 public static class MessageEvent { 

   public  String title;
    }
```

**in CallFragment declare it**

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {  
   adapter.addData(title.toString());
};
```

**Register in your fragment from you setup ContactDataAdapter**

```
@Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

**Call the event**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactDataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.titleTv.setText(arrList.get(position).toString());
    holder.conIv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            MessageEvent event=new MessageEvent();
            event.title= holder.titleTv.getText().toString();
            EventBus.getDefault().post(event);

            //CallFragment cf = new CallFragment();
            //CallDataAdapter cd = new CallDataAdapter();
            //String t = holder.titleTv.getText().toString();
            //cf.addItem(t.toString());
            //cd.addData(t);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Added " + t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```